# How do I update multiple pages automatically in html?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website that will house a web book (a book that is posted paragraph by paragraph on the website, like a webcomic).

My problem is that every time I make a page for a new post, I need to switch the `href` to go to the latest post. This wouldn't be a problem with very few pages, but as I post more, the amount of pages will stack up, and nobody has the time to go through and switch all of the files around.

How can I automatically change the `href` in all of the pages at one time? For further example:

```html
<li><a href="prologue2.html">Home</a></li>
```

I have three prologue posts: `prologue.html`, `prologue1.html`, and `prologue2.html`. The last one is the latest. If I were to make another one (`prologue3.html`), I would then want to change the `href` to `prologue3.html` in all of these existing files. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You might want to consider using non-static pages—still served as HTML—but generated dynamically by the server. A content management system might be one that you're looking for, or you can give [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) a try.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One would be setting a variable in Javascript or PHP. Change the variable once and display the variable in multiple pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to always name your 'latest' post the same thing (like `latest.html`) so you don't have to change the link in your `href` tag.

When you add a new post, just change the previous `latest.html` to whatever you think it should be called (like `prologue-1.html`), before adding the new `latest.html` file.

*Better yet* is to have two copies of the 'latest' post: one named `latest.html` and another named what it should be called (like `prologue-1.html`). Then, when you add a new post, you just overwrite the current `latest.html` with your latest post without having to worry about renaming the previous `latest.html` post first.

Comment: for the most part, this definitely helps. Thank you.